# Iptables to modify source ip. Nothing in POSTROUTING chain log

Tags: asterisk, iptables, nat

Here is a little picture

```
Asterisk eth1 10.254.254.2/28-------------  Many Good  Guys
eth1:1 192.168.83.5/32-----------  192.168.59.3 Bad Guy Peer
```

I have an Asterisk which is connected with several peers.  Some of them are connected through 
eth1 and one the badest through alias eth1:1.
Then my asterisk send invite to peers it goes with the eth1 source. So for the bad guy I need to change my source ip to 192.168.83.5 As far as I know it can be done with iptables.

So I tried the rule

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.254.254.2 -d 192.168.59.3 -j SNAT
>   --to 192.168.83.5

nothing happens.
When I log I can see send packets in INPUT and OUTPUT chains with :

> iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -s 10.254.254.2 -d 192.168.59.3
>   -j LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix "OUTPUT"
>
> iptables -t filter -A INPUT-i eth1 -s 192.168.59.3 -d 192.168.83.5 -j
>   LOG --log-level 7 --log-prefix "OUTPUT"

but I don’t see any in POSTROUTING chain with:

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.254.254.2 -d 192.168.59.3 -j LOG
>   --log-level 7 --log-prefix "POSTROUTING"

That is I have nothing to SNAT(((

At the same time the traffic from other peers is visible in POSTROUTING log. What can it be?
Any thoughts, wishes, kicks would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The solution has been found!!
I didn' t find a way to make my iptables work. But know i know how to do it without iptables at all.
So generally speaking my task was to modify|mask|replace my  source ip of eth1 with eth1:1 ip.
By the way i use CentOS 5.8
And there is a command:

> ip route add

which gives you ability to point scr address unlike the `route` command.

so

> ip route add 192.168.59.3/32 via 10.254.254.1 dev eth1 src
>   192.168.83.5

is doing just what i need.
Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. Reason is simple, asterisk will set in packet source addres=address of eth1.

You can start enother asterisk same host(with other config dir). I am sorry, i not know other simple variants.